# Wildcard bundle id greys out required options

Tags: ios, bundle

I'm trying to register a wildcard bundle ID, but when I select wildcard, it greys out an option that I need - media device discovery.

I think I need this capability to play audio via bluetooth? So why can I not use a wildcard? This will significantly increase the overhead for all the apps I need to deploy!

Answer (score 0):

You can only use a Wildcard App ID for all apps and app targets that do not enable app-specific capabilities, like APNS, In-App Pay...etc, the Media device discovery in your case. That's why it is opt out. For that you must have to use the Explicit ID.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1713/_index.html